# problem with rendering of property (django)

Tags: python, html, django, properties, output

I'm trying to learn about property. I'm trying to get an output but it doesn't work what is the problem?

```
class ShiftPlace(models.Model):
 name = models.ManyToManyField(to=DashboardEmploye)
 adress = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
 postcode = models.CharField(max_length=60)
 HouseNumber = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
 city = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=200)
 startTime = models.TimeField(auto_now=False)
 endTime = models.TimeField(auto_now=False)
 comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10000)


@property
def Get_time(self):
    return 41
```

html

```
 <div class="card"><li>Totale Uren gepland: {{shiftplace.Get_time}}</li></div>
```

view

```
def dashboard(request):
employe = DashboardEmploye.objects.all()
shift = ShiftPlace.objects.all()
employeInfo = Employe.objects.all()
context ={
    'employe': employe,
    'employeInfo': employeInfo,
    'shift': shift

}
return render(request, 'dash/dashboard.html', context)
```

Comment: There is no `shiftplace` key in your context so the first part of variable lookup will fail.

Comment: Yea. it should be `{{shift.Get_time}}` to even have some chance of working